# Figure out if Carat is in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is there any way to tell if the Mouse Carat is in a `TextBox`? Basically, if the carat is in the `TextBox`, you can start typing and the text will appear in the `TextBox` but if the Carat is not in the `TextBox`, when you start typing, nothing will happen, Is it possible to tell if it is or isn't in the `TextBox`?

Sort of like what the `TextBox` where you put your password in when you log in to your computer.

Sorry if this sounds confusing, it is sort of confusing to me.

Comment: Are you talking about the cursor?

Comment: No, i can do that, it is the thing that blinks to show where you will start typing.

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't know it had a name.

Comment: it is the blinking | that i am talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check if the `Textbox` has focus by using the [`Control.ContainsFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus.aspx) property.

Comment: @Dozer789 - Use the `ContainsFocus` property